# How can I use AVAssetDownloadTask to download a FairPlay-encrypted AVURLAsset instance that has not yet been streamed?

Tags: ios, avassetdownloadtask, avassetresourceloaderdelegate

I'm trying to use [`AVAssetDownloadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetdownloadtask?language=objc) to download and play FairPlay-encrypted audio content offline. I kept getting an error like this in [`urlSession:task:didCompleteWithError:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontaskdelegate/1411610-urlsession?language=objc):

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11863 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This content is no longer available., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}

My flow was:

- Create an `AVURLAsset` using a URL like `https://my.cdn.com/playlist.m3u8`
- Set its [resource loader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset/1389118-resourceloader?language=objc)'s [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloader/1388314-setdelegate?language=objc)
- Give it to a player in the form of an `AVPlayerItem`
- Using the [methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloaderdelegate/1388121-resourceloader?language=objc) in [`AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloaderdelegate?language=objc), look for a URL beginning the scheme `skd`, download the CKC, [get the persist-able form](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloadingrequest/1623676-persistentcontentkeyfromkeyvendo?language=objc), and hand it back to the resource loader request

All of this worked, and was done in the same way as in Apple's [HLSCatalog sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HLSCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html). But downloading would still give me the above error, even though plugging the same playlist and key URLs into the sample code would download fine.

What I finally figured out was that `AVAssetDownloadTask` will only download an `AVURLAsset` *instance* that has already been streamed and given its decryption keys (via the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`) and that is not associated with a player. I can't just make a new `AVURLAsset` using the same URL as what is already playing and download it. So it seems that in order to download arbitrary FairPlay content, I have to:

- Make an `AVURLAsset`
- Make an `AVPlayer` and set its volume to 0
- Give it the asset and play it
- Wait until it requests its keys from the resource loader and starts playing
- Give it to a download task and deassociate it with the player

But this seems horrible. It can't be true.

So, my question: **How do I download a FairPlay-encrypted AVURLAsset without having streamed that specific instance of it before?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out you set [`preloadsEligibleContentKeys`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloader/1386939-preloadseligiblecontentkeys?language=objc) to true on the asset's resource loader. Then you can download:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:self.currDownload.url];
[asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
asset.resourceLoader.preloadsEligibleContentKeys = YES;
AVAssetDownloadTask *task = [self.downloadSession assetDownloadTaskWithURLAsset:asset assetTitle:self.currDownload.title assetArtworkData:nil options:@{AVAssetDownloadTaskMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey: @(265000)}];
task.taskDescription = self.currDownload.title;
[task resume];
```

Comment: this saved my day.